# Flink: NoClassDefFoundError when runnig a Table API query

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a streaming Table API query and want to write the resulting `Table` into a `.csv` file using the `table.writetoSink(sink)` method.

When I run the program, I got the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/commons/compiler/CompileException
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:580)
at org.apache.flink.api.table.FlinkPlannerImpl.rel(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:102)
at org.apache.flink.api.table.BatchTableEnvironment.sql(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:132)
at table_streaming_test.main(table_streaming_test.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

I have also included the commons-compiler.jar file in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's Table and SQL API is built on Apache Calcite which depends on `commons-compiler` from `org.codehaus.janino`.

The error message suggests that the `commons-compiler` dependency is not included in your application. One approach is to built a fat jar containing all dependencies of your application. Flink's quickstart Maven architypes ([Java](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html) and [Scala](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/quickstart/scala_api_quickstart.html)) provide a blueprint for that. Another approach is to add all required dependencies to the `./lib` folder of your Flink setup.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I have included the commons-compiler jar in my project, but it leads to following error

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate java compiler` `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No implementation of org.codehaus.commons.compiler is on the class path
 at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompilerFactoryFactory.getDefaultCompilerFactory(CompilerFactoryFactory.java:58)
 at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.JaninoRelMetadataProvider.compile(JaninoRelMetadataProvider.java:415)`

Comment: Maybe your version is not compatible with the version that Calcite expects. However, you should not need to explicitly include transitive dependencies. Including `flink-table` and building a fat jar with all dependencies should be enough.